# Making a list off all users in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a list of all the users on my Django setup in order to list who is working on a device, currently it pulls the usernames.

```
REPAIRED_BY = (
    ('BLANK', 'Not Assigned'),
    ('USER1', User.objects.all()),
)
```

but it does not allow me to list them in a string format (i.e. Joe Smith). I am able to get the first and last name using value_list but it appears as a tuple. ('Joe','Smith')

```
repaired_by = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=REPAIRED_BY, default='BLANK')
```

It needs to be able to switch users to different devices. User 1 is working on computers 1 & 2 while user 2 is working on computer 3

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you would want to use a ForeignKey field, to bind a User to a Device.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

```
repaired_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

Comment: That almost works but it removed my list. The plan/idea is to allow a dropdown menu to assign different users to the device (i.e. Joe Smith is working on Computer 1 while John Smith is working on Computer 2). I'll add that for more information

Comment: Thats what ForeignKey is intented for. If you look in your django-admin, you will see a dropdown with all your Users

Comment: The docs for [ModelForm FieldTypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) state that ForeignKey uses a ModelChoiceField.. which would give the dropdown list.

Comment: I added the  `null=true` like suggested and that did fix the issue, however, it's pull them up as user names, I am trying to pull first and last name so it shows up as Joe Smith instead of jsmith

Comment: For that you would have to change the *__unicode__* method of django auth User class. Some ideas are presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062493/override-django-user-model-unicode)

Comment: I managed to figure it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966483/django-show-get-full-name-instead-or-username-in-model-form) Thanks to @maccinza for the suggestion to override the unicode and OP for the answer to getting my user information.

Answer (score -1):

> in order to list [...] does not allow me to list them in a string
>   format (i.e. Joe Smith). I am able to get the first and last name
>   using value_list but it appears as a tuple. ('Joe','Smith')

I'm not sure I get your issue right, but getting a convenient name display from a tuple of name parts is trivial:

```
t = ('Joe','Smith') 
print(" ".join(t))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that does not help enough. I need a drop down menu, (which the first suggestion helped with).